# iPhone 6 simulator doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

My code for ball going to end of bottom of screen and then regenerate back at top of screen...

```
if(ball.center.y >666){
ball.center=CGPointMake(ONE.center.x, -30);
```

In iPhone 6 simulator, the farthest the ball goes down is ball.center.y >585 and only then it regenerates. But how come it doesn't go all the way down to ball.center.y >666?

I have retina 4.7HD and retina 5.5HD launch images placed.
Whether I use auto layout and size classes or no auto layout and no size classes the ball doesn't go lower than ball.center.y >585.

Please help, i don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Something is wrong with your launch images. It definitely looks like simulator thinks it's running in scale-up mode.

Comment: It's loading the iPhone 6 simulator screen but i played around with the coordinated and the coordinates won't go bigger than a 4inch screen iPhone 5. In other words the iPhone 5 is loading inside the iPhone 6 simulator. Xcode 6.1 not giving me error with launch images. Retina 5.5HD launch image = 1242 x 2208 and Retina 4.7 HD launch image =750x1334.

Comment: Please post a screen shot of your project settings where you specify  launch image, and images in your assets catalog.